# Get the row number for a specific entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called Leaderboard with 2 columns, PlayerName and PlayerRating. I want to be able to access a specific PlayerName, get their PlayerRating but ALSO their rank (ex: are they first, 2nd, 10th?). I did some reading around and I did find a way, but I can't seem to translate it into PHP and actually print the value. Please keep in mind that I'm not very experienced with MySQLi or PHP.

I'm currently getting my PlayerRating the following way:

```
$CurrentRating = $Connection->query("SELECT CurrentRating FROM Leaderboard WHERE PlayerName='$PlayerName'")->fetch_assoc()["CurrentRating"];
```

I can just `echo $CurrentRating;` and job's done. Now to find the PlayerRank I found several posts explaining how my query should also have

```
SET @rank=0; SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 As rank
```

So the beginning I suppose would be:

```
query("SET @rank=0; SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 As rank, CurrentRating FROM Leaderboard [...]
```

But I can't seem to get it working and get a rank to print properly. I tried echoing `$CurrentRating["rank"]` and a few variations of the following:

```
$CurrentRank = $Connection->query("SET @rank=0; SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 As rank, SELECT CurrentRating FROM Leaderboard WHERE PlayerName='$PlayerName'")->fetch_assoc()["rank"];
```

Can someone please help me write this correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump() the $CurrentRank variable to see if the data is being stored in it?

Comment: Do you just want their rating and name?

Comment: As I mentioned, I can already display their name and rating properly, I just need to also display their rank. You can think of rating as a score I suppose if that's the confusing part.

Comment: I have not tried var_dump() however I'm not sure which variations of the many I've tried I should apply it to. Would you be so kind to write the full thing so I can test it? Thanks!

Comment: `mysqli_query()` can't run multiple queries at once.

Comment: I actually have multiple lines like that in other PHP files to other values from multiple tables and it works just fine.

Comment: But I do see how it would probably better if I limited the amount of queries and combine them for better performance.

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query()` can run several queries, but `mysqli_query()` isn't able to do that. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php - you should get SQL syntax errors if you run multiple queries separated by `;` when using `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: I'm using something like the following without any issues:
`$MatchesTotal = $Connection->query("SELECT MatchesTotal FROM Shop WHERE PlayerName='$PlayerName'")->fetch_assoc()["MatchesTotal"];

$MatchesRemaining = $Connection->query("SELECT MatchesRemaining FROM Shop WHERE PlayerName='$PlayerName'")->fetch_assoc()["MatchesRemaining"];`

Comment: In any case, if your query isn't working, the first step is to get the actual error thrown back at you, by using `echo $Connection->error`. I'll bet you a beer that it says you get a syntax error directly after `;`. Running several queries (like in the comment above) after one another is fine, but not in a single call.

Comment: Alright well let's just say I'll only do one single Query and all that I need to get from it is the rank of the player. So I know the PlayerName, Leaderboard is my table, I just need to know what rank that player is based on CurrentRating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries should be something like these when you want ranking based on CurrentRating.

**Query**

```
    SELECT 
       Leaderboard.PlayerName
     , Leaderboard.PlayerRating
     , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank
    FROM 
     Leaderboard
    CROSS JOIN(
      SELECT 
       @rank := 0
    )
      AS
        init_user_variable 
    ORDER BY 
     Leaderboard.CurrentRating DESC
```

When you want a ranking with where filter you should use this query inside a delivered table like this.

**Query**

```
     SELECT 
       Leaderboard_ranked.PlayerName
     , Leaderboard_ranked.PlayerRating
     , Leaderboard_ranked.rank 
    FROM (

        SELECT 
           Leaderboard.PlayerName
         , Leaderboard.PlayerRating
         , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank
        FROM 
         Leaderboard
        CROSS JOIN(
          SELECT 
           @rank := 0
        )
          AS
            init_user_variable 
        ORDER BY 
         Leaderboard.CurrentRating DESC

    ) 
      AS 
       Leaderboard_ranked
    WHERE
     Leaderboard_ranked.PlayerName = 'playername'
```

**PHP MySQLi Syntax**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("host/ip", "user", "password", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, [query]);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['PlayerName'] . " " . $row['PlayerRating'] . " " . $row['rank'] "<br />" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you also help me with how I would go about printing the "rank" value? What would be the correct PHP syntax?

Comment: @stefanplc updated mine answer with a PHP MySQLi connect/query example.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Leaderboard WHERE CurrentRating > ?
```

With users Current rating as a parameter should be more or less enough

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try!

Comment: This works great! This is what my syntax looks like: `$CurrentRating = $Connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Leaderboard WHERE CurrentRating>'1250'")->fetch_assoc()["COUNT(*)"];` where "1250" would be replaced dynamically through a variable. Will this method work alright even if I have lets say 5000 players and the person that's running this query was at rank 4500? I'm worried that it might be too slow or something like that if I have too many players. Thanks again!